# Auto-update an Android launcher

Tags: android, auto-update, launcher, kiosk-mode

I am developing an Android Business Application, it will be hosted on private channel. We want to use auto-update app, the problem is:

- it's a laucher (set to the default after install)
- with kiosk function (that is the reason why wrote a laucher)
- this is the only one visible and runnable app, so it is always running

My question is:

Will the app restart when it updates automatically and stay it the default launcher?

Or do I need to write 2 app:

- a launcher with kiosk funcions (single application mode)
- and the business app?

Comment: u got any solution i am facing same issue

Comment: I wrote 2 app: a launcher and a business app as @Aaron Gillion suggested.
If you use at least Android 5.0, you can use Screen pin (https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6118421?hl=en), so launcher app is not necessary.
The auto-update delay is unsystematic, I think it's depends on many things. (device, system, network type, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your kiosk setup is genius.

To answer your question, Android defaults are not reset when an app is updated, even when it is a launcher.

The way it usually works is, when you're in Play Store updating apps, you update something like Nova launcher, the update takes place because the foreground window is Google Play. But when you click the home button, it takes about 5 seconds to load up the new version of Nova launcher and your app icons slowly pop up everywhere (RAM refresh effect).

What I would recommend doing is to host your business app (or whatever needs updating) separately. Have your launcher track the foreground window's title every x seconds, so that your user doesn't open something from the notification bar or follow an advertisement link or stuff like that. I can tell you how to do that in Tasker: enable Tasker's accessibility service, then setup a profile to monitor the %WIN variable. Or if you have root, run `service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui` from your launcher onCreate to hide the status bar completely. This is all oversight, I do not know how you are specifically going about this.